# Rails 3: adding DISQUS gem for comments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, comments, disqus

Hi I'm trying to get DISCUS comments working in a Rails 3 app.There doesn't seem to be a good guide for setting this up.

The comment system won't show up and all I get in the view is this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">var disqus_developer = 1;</script><div id="disqus_thread"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://disqus.com/forums/gppublic/embed.js"></script>
<noscript><a href="http://gppublic.disqus.com/?url=ref">View the discussion thread</a></noscript>
```

Here's the step I took to set it up:

1) `gem install disqus`

2) place the config block in application.rb and add your specific account name

```
config.after_initialize do
    Disqus::defaults[:account] = "youraccountname"
    # so that the comments will load up in development environment
    Disqus::defaults[:developer] = true
    Disqus::defaults[:container_id] = "disqus_thread"
    Disqus::defaults[:show_powered_by] = false
    end
```

3) then place in my show view

```
<div id ="disqus_thread">
<%= disqus_thread %>
</div>
```

Where am I going wrong? Thanks

Comment: Did you restart your server? What appears inside #disqus_thread in the rendered HTML?

Comment: Yes I tried restarting the server :( The only thing that render in the html is this: <script type="text/javascript">var disqus_developer = 1;</script><div id="disqus_thread"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://disqus.com/forums/gppublic/embed.js"></script>
<noscript><a href="http://gppublic.disqus.com/?url=ref">View the discussion thread</a></noscript>

Comment: @Jesse do you by chance have DISQUS working on a rails app? Or have experience getting this to work?

Comment: @trying_hal9000 yes, but not using a gem... if you can make the page public I can help diagnose what javascript errors might be happening

Comment: Thanks I think it might have to do with me running locally, when I can get it up on a production server I'll know for sure, thanks again

Comment: Sure -- try heroku for easy production setup

Comment: Well nothing changed when I got it running on heroku, what did work was just copying their universal snippet of javascript and including my disqus_shortname. I'm not sure about the disqus gem or what I need it for since the javascript works.

Comment: I encountered the same problem while running the disqus gem. The generic code did not work for me. What should I do?

Comment: @coder from what I found the gem isn't really needed. If you just paste in the universal javascript code they supply at DISQUS.com and change out the 'shortname' with your username it works just fine. I found I had to be running in production to have the comments show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to use raw or html_safe.

```
 = raw disqus_thread
```

or

```
 = disqus_thread.html_safe
```